# Dirty Size on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode-instruments

How to minimize Dirty Size on iPhone app? I released my cache image but don't minimize Dirty Size. Someone have more tips?

Thanks!

Comment: [Here's how.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use instruments to check for memory loss due to retained but not leaked memory. The latter is unused memory that is still pointed to. Use Heapshot in the Allocations instrument on Instruments.

For HowTo use Heapshot to find memory creap, see: [bbum blog](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Basically there method is to run Instruments allocate tool, take a heapshot, run an intuition of your code and another heapshot repeating 3 or 4 times. This will indicate memory that is allocated and not released during the iterations.

To figure out the results disclose to see the individual allocations.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the picker to run, stop recording, search for there ivar (datePickerView), drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

Comment: Thank your reply, sorry my response slow. I checked it all! My problem is MEMORY_TINY, your DIRTY_SIZE does not reduce.

Comment: Sorry, don't is MEMORY_TINY is MALLOC_TINY